# Modulus not Riemann integrable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Suppose a function $f\colon I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is (complex) Riemann integrable (cf. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Complex_Riemann_Integral).

Is it possible for $\vert f \vert$ (modulus) not to be integrable? I can't think of an example as by definition both the real and imaginary part have to be integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f=u+iv$ with $u,v:I \to \mathbb R.$

If $f$ is complex Riemann integrable then $u$ and $v$ are Riemann integrable, hence $u^2+v^2$ is Riemann integrable, therefore $|f|= \sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ is Riemann integrable